# What traditional Jewish song/dance is this?

Tags: wedding, music, dance

What song starts playing at 1:33 in this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYuYojyDwN4

I am working on a play about extremism and antisemitism for the Slovak National Theater and we'd like to use the instrumental. I am not familiar with the Jewish culture - is the song/dance well-known, or not? If so, is it available anywhere recorded in higher quality? I used Shazam, but with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: It's from the [wedding scene in Fiddler on the Roof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGBG8mCt59s&t=1m13s).